# Show localized date format based on computer settings in angular 2

Tags: angular, momentjs, date-formatting

I see in http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ the "Localized formats" options such as `L`.

(In the browser) I expected this might change the display of a date from `mm/dd/yyyy` to `dd/mm/yyyy` depending on the user's computer/browser locale settings, however this doesn't seem to be the case. (I changed my OS X settings to test, and didn't see any browser-specific settings).

Is there a way to accomplish this in Moment currently? I'm not looking to display different languages/translations, but rather just different date formats based on the user's country/locale settings.

If not, is this possible/practical at all? I'm not sure of the reliability/usefulness of stuff like `toLocaleDateString`.

Comment: Moment by default uses `en` locale, you have to set another locale using [`moment.locale()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) or [`locale()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/) to make the output of _Localized formats_ (e.g. `moment().format("L")`) change.

Comment: The localized formats, such as "L", are specifically designed to not use the browser's setting. They use moment's internationalization support, as describe under the [i18n](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/) section.
Even isn't changes, you'll find there are differences between English (US) and English (England):one of which is the date format,so moment wraps it all together.

Comment: Have you tried with datepicker in angular..?

Comment: The date picker is used to select a date, i am displaying this picked date ,later, in a table and want to change its format based on the locale

Comment: one alternative is this: [toLoacaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), but this is not supported in all browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use moment [`localeData`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/) and `longDateFormat` to get locale specific format.

Here an example showing how to get format for a given locale and how to display a moment object accordingly:

```js
function changeLang(value){  
  // Get locale data
  var localeData = moment.localeData(value);
  var format = localeData.longDateFormat('L');
  var res = moment().format(format);
  
  $("#format").html(format);
  $("#result").html(res);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

<select onchange="changeLang(value)">
  <option value="en">EN</option>
  <option value="en-CA">en-CA (Canada)</option>
  <option value="eo">eo (Esperanto)</option>
  <option value="de">DE</option>
  <option value="it">IT</option>
  <option value="hu">hu (Hungarian)</option>
  <option value="ja">ja (Japanese)</option>
  <option value="lv">lv (Latvian)</option>
  <option value="fr">FR</option>
  <option value="zh-hk">zh-hk - Chinese (Hong Kong)</option>
  <option value="ar-ly">ar-ly - Arabic (Lybia)</option>
</select>

<div id="format"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine for me.
Also, we can use window.navigator.language to detect user's browser locale language as :-
var value = moment.locale(window.navigator.language)
and then use your code